# How to convert Entity Framework to SQL command?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I want convert this EF code to a SQL command:

```
var parents = db.Fuels.Select(A => A.Parent).Distinct();
var data = db.Fuels.Where(B => !parents.Any(A => A == B.ID))
                   .OrderBy(A => A.Type);
```

I tried to write the SQL command but it does not work:

```
select *
from Fuel as a
where id not in (select id from Fuel as b
                 where a.ID = b.Parent)
```

Table structure:

```
ID      INT PK,
Name    NVARCHAR(50) Checked,
Parent  INT FK
```

Table data

[image: Table Data]

I want this output

[image: i want like output]

Comment: You could always use SQL Profiler or similar to see the SQL that Entity Framework is generating.

Comment: Can you explain more or write steps ?

Comment: Assuming you have Server Management Studio installed, it has something called [SQL Server Profiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sql-server-profiler/sql-server-profiler) installed, accessible via the Tools menu. You would create a new session, start it running, and then run your Entity Framework code. The profiler would capture any queries made against the target database, so you could see the SQL that EF generated for your LINQ query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the query you are looking for:

```
;with parents as (select distinct parent as ID from @Fuel)
select * from @Fuel where id not in (select Id from @Fuel where Id in(select Id from 
parents))
```

SQL fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=dc39433e40541b814936f3dfea725c6b